# Login to azure linux vm using service principal

Tags: ssh, azure-active-directory, azure-virtual-machine, rbac

I created a linux VM in azure.
Added the extention `AADLoginForLinux` to the VM.

Created a service principal in AAD.
Added role assignment `Virtual Machine Administrator Login` for the application ID of the service principal.

Now I'm trying to login to the VM using that service principal:

```
az login --service-principal -u <test-sp-app-id> -p <test-sp-secret-value> --tenant <tenant-id>

az ssh vm -n <vm-name> -g <resource-group-name>
```

But getting an error:

```
Code: AuthorizationFailed

Message: The client '85da262dghfgjhj' with object id '85da262dghfgjhj' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/read' over scope '/subscriptions/4753465465465/resourceGroups/rg-test/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/nic-jb-test' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.
```

**What are the actual RBAC roles a service principal needs to be able to log in to a VM?**

**Is it possible to log in to azure VM using the service principal? Am I missing any step here?**

- **Try 1:**

  Added the `Reader` role for the VM at the resource group level.

  The `az ssh` command now triggered a device login https://microsoft.com/devicelogin in the browser. It won't accept the service principal as a user.
- **Try 2:**

  Used parameter `--local-user`, still the CLI prompts for device auth. :

`az ssh vm -n <vm-name> -g <resource-group-name> --local-user <test-sp-app-id>`

as per the docs:

> ```
>  az ssh vm : SSH into Azure VMs or Arc Servers.
>     Users can login using AAD issued certificates or using local user credentials. We recommend
>     login using AAD issued certificates. To SSH using local user credentials, you must provide
>     the local user name using the --local-user parameter.
> ```

**References:**

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/howto-vm-sign-in-azure-ad-linux#configure-role-assignments-for-the-vm
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/howto-vm-sign-in-azure-ad-linux#log-in-by-using-the-azure-ad-service-principal-to-ssh-into-the-linux-vm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

Created virtual machine and added the extention `AADLoginForLinux` to the vm like below:

[image]

Created service principal and tried the same command make sure to add contributor role to service principal like below:

```
az login --service-principal -u <test-sp-app-id> -p <test-sp-secret-value> --tenant <tenant-id>
```

[***Output***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nqeky.png)

```
  {
    "cloudName": "AzureCloud",
    "homeTenantId": "d0d018b3-c4bb-44b1-a9ec-0xxxxxxx",
    "id": "55d5f6cc-a2a3-49de-9109-XXXXXXX",
    "isDefault": true,
    "managedByTenants": [],
    "name": "Free Trial",
    "state": "Enabled",
    "tenantId": "d0d018b3-c4bb-44b1-a9ec-XXXXXXXX",
    "user": {
      "name": "b218367f-7d8d-411e-90d4-XXXXXXX",
      "type": "servicePrincipal"
    }
  }
]
```

In virtual machine added role assignment `Virtual Machine Administrator Login` like below:

[image]

When I try to run the command in windows powershell login into ssh successfully like below:

```
az ssh vm -n <vm-name> -g <resource-group-name>
```

**[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkacP.png)**

```
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.4.3
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-1104-azure x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

  System information as of Mon Mar 20 12:27:06 UTC 2023

  System load:  0.0               Processes:           95
  Usage of /:   5.2% of 28.89GB   Users logged in:     0
  Memory usage: 23%               IP address for eth0: 10.1.0.4
  Swap usage:   0%


 * Introducing Expanded Security Maintenance for Applications.
   Receive updates to over 25,000 software packages with your
   Ubuntu Pro subscription. Free for personal use.

     https://ubuntu.com/azure/pro

Expanded Security Maintenance for Applications is not enabled.

5 updates can be applied immediately.
5 of these updates are standard security updates.
To see these additional updates run: apt list --upgradable

5 additional security updates can be applied with ESM Apps.
Learn more about enabling ESM Apps service at https://ubuntu.com/esm

New release '20.04.5 LTS' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.


Last login: Mon Mar 20 09:41:54 2023 from 49.207.215.159
To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo <command>".
See "man sudo_root" for details.
```

Comment: What did you do to resolve the initial problem? Also, please share all explanation **in text form**, not hidden in screenshots

Comment: Hi @NicoHaase I have edited my answer with proper commands please check